# How to check whether the job is disabled or Not in sqlserver management studio 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

As part of the holiday processing some of the jobs are disabled in sql server using script.

They are not disabled manually.
Now when we see the jobs there is a check mark for enable entity.
And when we right click on the job the instead of enable thing being highlighted disable entity is highlighted.
Now we are getting doubt whether jobs are disabled or not.
How to check it through a query is there any status bit which tells us state of the job.
Whether it is disabled or enabled.
Please suggest/advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT name, enabled, * 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE enabled = 0
```

The above query will bring all disabled jobs. What you are seeing is certainly strange to me too.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the jobs folder and select Refresh to update the status icons and context menu.